# How to understand the Fresnel relation $1+R=T$?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, conservation-laws, reflection, scattering, refraction

From the perspective of energy conservation, we are familiar with the relation $T+R=1$ (Set the incident wave amplitude as 1, $T$ and $R$ are Fresnel transmission and reflection coefficient, supposing no energy absorbed by the material). However, in the book "Electromagnetic Wave theory" written by Kong Jin Au (MIT) when deducing the reflection and transmission for TE or TM waves, he has used the relation $1+R=T$ and it really confused me. Could anyone explain the reason?

[image: Reflection and transmission of TE waves][image: deduction 1][image: deduction 2]

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that $R,T$ as defined in your text are the coefficients of the electric field, not of the intensity.

The reason for the relation $R+1=T$ is simply that the electric field should be continuous across the boundary. Outside the material, you have an incident wave (coefficient of $1$) and the reflected wave (coefficient of $R$). Inside the material you have only the transmitted wave with coefficient $T$.

For continuity then you expect the electric field just outside the material matches that just inside the material, in other words $1+R=T$.